# How can update my broken CUDA packages?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, cuda

How I can fix the following problem? I want to update both these CUDA packages.

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

    cuda-cudart-dev-11-2: Depends: cuda-cudart-11-2 (>= 11.2.152) but it is not installed
    cuda-libraries-11-2: Depends: cuda-cudart-11-2 (>= 11.2.152) but it is not installed
                         Depends: cuda-nvrtc-11-2 (>= 11.2.152) but 11.2.152-1 is installed
                         Depends: libcublas-11-2 (>= 11.4.1.1043) but 11.4.1.1043-1 is installed
                         Depends: libcusparse-11-2 (>= 11.4.1.1152) but 11.4.1.1152-1 is installed
                         Depends: libnpp-11-2 (>= 11.3.2.152) but 11.3.2.152-1 is installed
                         Depends: libnvjpeg-11-2 (>= 11.4.0.152) but 11.4.0.152-1 is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your packages are not broken, they need to be updated/installed. Try something like this:

```
apt-get install cuda-cudart-dev cuda-libraries
```